# org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Connection is broken: "session closed"

Tags: h2, openjpa

I'm using [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) 1.3.162 with [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) 2.1.1 for a small desktop application written in Java.

For some reason I get following exception in random places of my code.

```
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Connection is broken: "session closed" [90067-162] {SELECT COUNT(t0.id) FROM Visitor t0 WHERE (t0.EngineId = ?)} [code=90067, state=90067]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:281)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:261)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:72)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:313)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:158)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$RefCountConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCStoreManager.java:1653)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:561)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:541)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.prepareStatement(SelectImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:420)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:391)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl$PackingResultObjectProvider.open(QueryImpl.java:2070)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.singleResult(QueryImpl.java:1320)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1242)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007)
```

My `persistence.xml` is pretty simple, nothing special really

```
<persistence-unit name="openjpa"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.mine.reporting.data.IpInfo</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:database"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.H2Dictionary"/>

        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

But everything works fine if I replace OpenJPA with [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) (ex-TopLink) which leads me to conclusion that problem is in OpenJPA.

What am I not doing right ?

Comment: I don't know why the session was closed, but you should consider using a different database URL. The one you use means the database file is stored relative to the current working directory, which is a bit dangerous. I suggest to use an absolute path instead (`jdbc:h2:/data/db`), or relative to the current user home directory (`jdbc:h2:~/data/db`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode=always`. This will tell OpenJPA to get one connection per EM and hold onto it. This might make the problem go away, but it won't solve the root issue of why your connections seem to be going bad.

I believe that on 2.1.1 OpenJPA will insert DBCP as a connection pool between JPA and the database, perhaps there is a problem with detecting bad connections.?

Comment: It turned out it was caused by the fact that connection was being closed in main thread while `SwingWorker` was using EntityManager in another thread :) So `<property name="openjpa.Multithreaded" value="true"/>` helped. But your suggestion helped me fix another bug. Thanks!